# Creating a mobile layout that looks like the landscape version while in portrait

Tags: html, iphone, css, mobile, viewport

I'm working on a website for job listings that needs to integrate a widget from SmartRecruiters and have run into an issue with the mobile layout.

I'm using the viewport tag as `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />` which works really well for a landscape orientation. The issue is that the SmartRecruiters table that lists the job openings does not shrink to be narrow enough when in portrait mode and requires the user to scroll horizontally.

How can I make the portrait layout zoom out to the same width as the landscape layout that works really well?

Comment: The question

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006812/html5-boilerplate-meta-viewport-and-width-device-width>

might help.

Comment: I looked at that one but don't see how I can get something to zoom out more