# Meta viewport and width=device-width vs. percent dimentions

Tags: css, mobile, viewport, viewport-units

I am trying to make sure I properly understand the way the Meta viewport tag works when setting  width=device-width.

Would it be a correct statement that when working on a mobile device with
`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">` usage of pixel units is (or should be) treated as if they are given on a grid that is 320 pixel wide? i.e. an element with width:160px would take up (160/320 = 50%) of the screen?

This behavior does not seem to work when running on a desktop browser,
so assuming that I want to get the same design on mobile and desktop, should/can I use either percentages or the `vw/vh` units?

Comment: *If* `device-width` evaluates to 320 CSS pixels for a particular device+orientation+browser combination, then yes, an element of width 160px would be half the screen width. But other combinations will evaluate `device-width` to other values.

Comment: o.k. - I am confused... So if the designer said they design a page based on a width of 1080px and that some button in the design is 210px and I should have 4 such buttons in a row (totaling 840px with the remaining space between them....)
and suppose I do have the meta tag - what size should I give my images?

Comment: Well, really you need a new designer... But if you want 4 images in a row taking approx 80% of the available width, you'd give each image a width of 20% (or 20vw). That's the same with or without the meta tag.

Comment: We are always in a process of learning. I respect my designers work and don't appreciate the first part of the comment. 
Lets say that you actually wrote that my designer should make some changes to the way she works (i.e. Learn) and I would still be happy to understand what would be those changes. I am sure she would be happy to improve.

Comment: Fair enough. She needs to stop thinking in terms of fixed size pixel based layouts and design with knowledge that a multitude of output devices will be used with very differing properties.

Comment: Yes. I agree and we already spoke of that. The issue still is that even when considering that, eventually sizes for stuff need to be picked... and I am not sure how we should pick those sizes and what units to use.
Consider again the desire to have 4 buttons that do stuff...
what would be the right "thinking flow" about designing something like that other then saying that we understand that in extreme situations we might want to to have those buttons positioned in a single column layout, in some other we would like to have them in a 2x2 matrix and above that we might want to have a single row

Comment: how would we choose the SIZE for those buttons? and how many pixels should we have in the actual images for those buttons (or icons on those buttons) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that CSS pixels and device pixels are not the same thing. The number of pixels when you set something to `width: 160px` in CSS relates to CSS pixels, which have very little to do with the actual pixels of the device.

Mobile browsers (on reasonably modern smartphones) create a "fake" viewport, that is emulating a desktop-width browser size, that is also zoomed out so that it fits on the screen. The measurements for this fake viewport is usually somewhere around 800-1000 CSS pixels wide (iPhones, for example, use 980px). This is to make sure that non-optimized sites still display OK on phones, as you can zoom in on specific parts etc.

When you use the meta viewport tag with `width=device-width`, you are telling the device that your site is adapted for viewing on *any* viewport size, and that you don't want the "fake desktop" measurement.

Instead, the browser should set the number of CSS pixels that fit on the screen to what is considered the "ideal" number of pixels for that device. On old iPhones, that was actually 320 pixels. On iOS devices with a retina screen, the CSS-pixel-to-device-pixel ratio is different, so the screen is 640px wide, but the ideal number of CSS pixels is still only 320. On other smartphones, the measurement is different - usually anything from 300 - 500 pixels on a smartphone.

If you want your layout to adapt to the number of CSS pixels, you are probably better off leaving the specific pixel measurements out of it and use percentages. 50% of the viewport will always be 50% of the viewport no matter how many CSS pixels you have to play with.

Comment: so basicly I got it upside down? stating `width=device-width` means that it can choose whatever value if sees fit for the number of css pixels? what happens when I select an actual value there? e.g. width=320 ? or width=1080? 
Why is the ideal number of pixels for the iOS 320 when the screen actually has 640? is it to make sure the css pixels are "big enough"?
would it be correct to say that you should use width=device-width when you DO want to get different values so you will be able to adapt the layout based on those values?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track: setting `width=device-width` means that the device gets to choose how "big" the viewport is in terms of pixels, e.g. for responsive layouts. If you set `width=320` (or any other value) there, it means that any device will use a width of 320 (CSS) pixels as the width of the viewport. That is usually not a very good choice, since there are so many devices with so many different viewports. Your layout will be scaled up on tablets, for example.

Comment: The iOS devices started out being 320 pixels wide (in portrait), so people started designing for that. When the retina screens came out, they had 4x as many pixels (2x width, 2x height), so "mobile" websites designed for 320 would look tiny. Hence, they emulated a "2x" zoom, so 1 CSS pixel = 2x2 device pixels. Nowadays, there are tons of different values for this, so the ideal number of pixels for each device can differ, but most of them stay in the 320-400-ish region, in terms of CSS pixels available for layout.

Comment: Oh, one final thing. The `initial-scale` thing also sets the viewport width, based on a zoom factor of 1 being equal to `device-width`. 
If you use the `initial-scale=1` declaration together with the `width=device-width` declaration (which you should - it prevents some inconsistent behavior), most mobile browsers will pick the larger of the 2. I highly recommend checking out Peter-Paul Kock's writings on this subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8J6EdpXdzqc

Comment: Thank you very much for this link. I just finished watching it and it was very good. but even more then answering my Qs it left me with several new ones such as what Units should we use and how should we decide on sized for stuff, when trying to design some UI that should be usable on any size of device...

Comment: Welcome to the world of responsive design! :-)
How to do RWD right is complex, but rewarding (and a separate question). But basically, I'd say the important bit is to stay flexible: design for change (changing layouts, changing devices) and treat anything with a fixed size as a potential warning signal. Good luck! :-)

Comment: Got any good videos to recommend in this topic?
Not about how to do RWD but about how to THINK RWD...

Comment: Not a video, but a good starting point for responsive patterns is Brad Frost's "This is responsive" - http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/

Comment: Thanks Emil, It looks like a very good resource on how to do things, and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

More often than not, there is absolutely no need for these harmful declarations:

```
maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no
```

My eyes are not very good and so often I find fonts used on web pages uncomfortably tiny. And what can be more annoying, if the site prevents me from zooming to be able to read it?

If you still think otherwise - please read carefully this article: http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho

Quotes from there (emphasis mine):

#### Declaring maximum scale

> Setting a maximum scale means setting a maximum zoom. On a website where the access to the information is the top priority (most, if not all, websites), setting a `maximum-scale=1` won’t allow the user to zoom. This might seem unimportant if you have a responsive website, but there are **lots of cases when the user might need to zoom**: small body font (at least, for the user’s needs), checking some details in a photograph, etc. **Don’t trigger an accessibility issue just for aesthetic reasons.**

#### User-scalable=no

> This parameter removes the ability to zoom in or zoom out, and it’s **even worse** than `maximum-scale`. If there’s a really special reason to use it (e.g., you are coding a web app and need to avoid zooming in form inputs), try adding and removing it with JavaScript, just for the action you want to fix. Anyway, remember that **smartphone users are used to zoom in and out** any website, so having to zoom out after filling a form might be a default behavior and **you don’t probably have to fix it**.

#### Combo breaker

> Now picture the combo-breaker: a non responsive website (fixed layout, about 960px width) with a viewport tag like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="..., maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

> Congratulations, your website zoomed to the first 300px or 400px of the top left corner, the user can’t zoom out and the only way to access the information is by patiently viewing the website in pieces of 300px width. A whole experience screwed up by an extra tag.